# how to get my success message to not show when there is an error

Tags: java, xml, fxml, scenebuilder

When the code is run, and I enter the credentials incorrectly, the successfully added message appears along with the error message and I am not sure why this is happening. We need to show an error message and a success message for our work.
When the code is run, and I enter the credentials incorrectly, the successfully added message appears along with the error message and I am not sure why this is happening. We need to show an error message and a success message for our work.

```
public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {
   private FadeTransition fade = new FadeTransition(
        Duration.millis(5000)
   );

Employee em = new Employee();
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    // TODO
     TV_id.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("ID"));
    TV_fname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("FirstName"));
    TV_lname.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("LastName"));
    TV_date.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("HireDate"));
    fade.setNode(label_success);
    fade.setFromValue(1.0);
    fade.setToValue(0.0);
    fade.setCycleCount(1);
    fade.setAutoReverse(false);
}


@FXML
private void handleButtonAddAction(ActionEvent event) {


    label_fail.setText("");
    label_success.setText("Successfully Added");
    int ID = 0, year = 0, month = 0, day = 0;
    String fname = "", lname = "";

    if (intValidation(TF_id) == true) {
        label_id.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_id.setVisible(false);
        ID = Integer.parseInt(TF_id.getText());
    } else {
        rec_id.setVisible(true);
        label_id.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (stringValidation(TF_fname) == true) {
        label_fname.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_fname.setVisible(false);
        fname = TF_fname.getText();
    } else {
        rec_fname.setVisible(true);
        label_fname.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (stringValidation(TF_lname) == true) {
        label_fname.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_lname.setVisible(false);
        lname = TF_lname.getText();
    } else {
        rec_lname.setVisible(true);
        label_lname.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (intValidation(TF_month) == true) {
        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_month.setVisible(false);
        month = Integer.parseInt(TF_month.getText());
    } else {
        rec_month.setVisible(true);
        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (intValidation(TF_day) == true) {
        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_day.setVisible(false);
        day = Integer.parseInt(TF_day.getText());
    } else {
        rec_day.setVisible(true);
        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (intValidation(TF_year) == true) {

        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#000000"));
        rec_year.setVisible(false);
        year = Integer.parseInt(TF_year.getText());
    } else {
        rec_year.setVisible(true);
        label_date.setTextFill(Color.web("#ff0000"));
    }
    if (!rec_id.isVisible() && !rec_fname.isVisible()
            && !rec_lname.isVisible() && !rec_month.isVisible()
            && !rec_day.isVisible() && !rec_year.isVisible()) {
        if (em.addEmployee(fname, lname, ID, year, month, day) == false) {
            label_fail.setText("No two employees can have the same ID.");
        } else {
            updateList();
            label_success.setVisible(true);
            fade.playFromStart();
            TF_id.setText("");
            TF_fname.setText("");
            TF_lname.setText("");
            TF_month.setText("");
            TF_day.setText("");
            TF_year.setText("");
        }

    }

}
 private void updateList() {
    TV_employee.getItems().clear();

}

private boolean intValidation(TextField txt) {
    if (txt.getText().isEmpty() || txt.getText() == null) {
        label_fail.setText("Error: You can not leave any fields blank.");
        return false;
    }
    try {
        int x = Integer.parseInt(txt.getText());
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        label_fail.setText("Error: " + txt.getText() + " is not an integer.");
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean stringValidation(TextField txt) {
    if (txt.getText().isEmpty() || txt.getText() == null) {
        label_fail.setText("Error: You can not leave any fields blank.");
        return false;
    } else if (txt.getText().matches(".*\\d.*")) {
        String invalidCharacters = txt.getText().replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        label_fail.setText("Error: You've entered illegal characters in a text field. "
                + "Please remove \"" + invalidCharacters + "\" "
                        + "from the highlighted field or enter a different value.");
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I expect is happening: The label_success is always visible. At the start it has no text so you won't see that it is visible, but this changes when you add the text to  the label at the beginning of the method. The fade is responsible for setting it's opacity to 0. But when you enter an invalid value the fade is never started, so it remains at it's starting value, which means it will be visible. You could solve this by moving the  `label_success.setText("Successfully Added");`  inside the final if-statement just above where you start your fade.

Also you can probably make your life more easy by separating the validation of the input from the visal setting of the labels into different methods as a lot is going on right now inside the same method.